# Why do Apple bloggers use Skype or Google Hangouts instead of iChat for video podcasts?

Tags: ichat, video-conference

I enjoy a few "talking heads" type of video podcasts by Apple bloggers. How come they don't use iChat? Doesn't iChat have group video conferencing or are there technical (as opposed to social) reasons to prefer skype over iChat for producing a video podcast?

Comment: My experience is that Skype is much less prone to freezing and dropped connections than ichat

Comment: Hopefully the hold gets removed because this is a superb question. One such reason is capture ability. If you used iChat you can capture the chat with a great deal of tricks and CPU%. For Skype there are special programs which allow the raw feed to be saved and edited for later use. Conferencing isn't as important as ease of editing to must people who do that stuff for a living

Comment: Thanks @AndrewU. As always, a good answer can save even a very poor question. (Not saying this is poor since I voted to reopen, just saying in general). Also, if tomg has details on compression quality statistics, that would make for an excellent answer.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the Apple community "didn't approve of the quality of this question." Can anyone please tell me what the problem was?

Answer (score 1):

- #### Awareness

  Many people know what Skype is — not many know about iChat in comparison. As soon as someone says 'video conference' the immediate response by many is 'Skype!'
- #### Familiarity

  Many of the older video podcasts use Skype because that's what they started with. Familiarity is very important with people that make video podcasts for a living. They see no reason to switch because Skype works well for them.
- #### Plugins

  There are a number of plugins made for Skype for recording the call, etc. This means that for those that use Skype they'd have no reason to switch to iChat since their favourite plugin isn't available that works with the rest of their equipment.
- #### Livestreaming

  Many video podcasts use Google Hangouts because of its ease of use for livestreaming it as well. Google Hangouts can be livestreamed with practically no preparation or equipment and then immediately made available on YouTube after, which is perfect for many.
- #### Number of People

  Google Hangouts can hold many more people than iChat/Skype, which makes it perfect for large events.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But your first 2 points surely couldn't apply to Apple bloggers (i.e. people who blog about Apple products and services for a living).